# Fourier transform and power series

Tags: fourier-transform, conformal-field-theory

My major is Physics so I am very naive about the Fourier transform, and its main use for me is to simplify analysis of physical problems with translational symmetry, turning some PDEs into ODEs.

I am computing a quantity (a holographic correlation function) $f(\vec{x})$ and I am able to obtain its Fourier transform $\tilde{f}(\vec{p}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int d^4\vec{x} f(\vec{x}) e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}$ in a close form as a formal series, with each term having an explicit but complicated expression, so no hope to sum up the series. What I want is to extract physical quantities from the first few powers in $\vec{x}$ of $f(\vec{x})$, for example it can look like
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{2\Delta}}(3x_1^2-x_2^2+o(\vec{x}^2))
\end{align}
My question is how do I obtain the data of power series in $\vec{x}$ of $f(\vec{x})$ from the Fourier transform $\tilde{f}(\vec{p})$. There is no way to get a simple closed form for $f(\vec{p})$, but I may be able to do a $\frac{1}{\vec{p}^2}$ expansion term by term in the formal series expression, since "short distance corresponds to large momentum". Even if I get the $\frac{1}{\vec{p}^2}$ expansion, it seems complicated to Fourier transform the powers, for example my Mathematica is not able to compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{2\Delta}}(3x_1^2-x_2^2)$.

In one word, I need to understand how the short distance behavior (power series in $\vec{x}$) of $f(\vec{x})$ is encoded in the Fourier transform $\tilde{f}(\vec{p})$, and what kind of large momentum data I need to extract it.

Comment: You want to extract some feature of $f$ from other "features" of $\hat f$? What features exactly are you talking about? Typically one may want to know the long distance behavior of correlation function, but what are your precise desiderata?

Comment: @lcv Thank you for your interests. I want the first few terms of power series expansion in $\vec{x}$ of $f(\vec{x})$, and I am wondering if I get it from the leading terms in the $\frac{1}{\vec{p}}$ expansion of $\tilde{f}(\vec{p})$.

Comment: In general the Fourier transform of $\hat f$ need not be analytic (having a convergent power series expansion). In order to be analytic it should decay sufficiently fast at infinity.

Comment: Those are essentially the wannabe moments of $\hat f$. I can post an answer tonight if  no one shows up.

Comment: @lcv In my case, I don't have a simple closed form of $\tilde{f}(\vec{p})$, it's expressed as a formal series, each term an explicit but complicated expression. I don't know if it is analytic, I am just looking for some way to do the computation, even if it's trying luck.

Comment: Normally an infinite series is not considered a closed form, so what do you mean by "close form as a formal series" in your question? Could you post the definitions of $f(\vec{x})$ and $\tilde{f}(\vec{p})$ of interest?

Comment: Mathematica 13.1.0.0 indicates $$\mathcal{F}_{x_1,x_2}\left[\frac{3 x_1^2-x_2^2}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right)^{2 \Delta}}\right](\omega_1,\omega_2)=-\frac{\pi ^2 2^{4-4 \Delta} \csc (2 \pi \Delta) \left(\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2\right)^{2 \Delta-3} \left((6 \Delta-5) \omega_1^2+(3-2 \Delta) \omega_2^2\right)}{\Gamma(2 \Delta) \Gamma(2 \Delta-1)}$$ using FourierParameters$\to\{1,1\}$.

Comment: @StevenClark Thank you for your help. Somehow my Mathematica 14.0.0.0 is not able to compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{3x_1^2-x_2^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{2\Delta}}$, but it finds the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{2\Delta}}$ to be $\frac{4^{1-2\Delta}\pi(p_x^2+p_y^2)^{2\Delta-1}\Gamma(1-2\Delta)}{\Gamma(2\Delta)}$. Then I can differentiate with respect to $p_x,p_y$ to get the same result as yours.

Answer (score 1):

The power series of $f$ in terms of it's Fourier transform $\hat f$

$$
f(x) = \int d^4 p \, e^{ip\cdot x} \hat{f}(p)
$$

(note that I changed the normalization of the Fourier transform) can be simply obtained, formally, by expanding the exponential

$$
f(x) \, {"="} \sum_{k=0} \frac{(i x)^k}{k!} \mu_k
$$

where the (wannabe) moments are

$$\mu_k =\int d^4 p \, p^k \hat{f}(p) \ .
$$
Clearly for the moments to exist $\hat f$ should decay sufficiently fast at infinity. This however does not guarantee that the power series of $f$ converge. A necessary condition is that $\hat f$ decays exponentially (being compactly supported, for example, would do as well, and implies even better regularity property of $f$).